# Network creation and manipulation in Python from two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, network-programming

I'm struggling with a programming problem which is described as follows. I have a first DataFrame which links customers to reference numbers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cus_id' : ['WAT_281', 'NIV_654', 'HUL_602', 'BRA_451'], 
                    'ref_num' : ['1410', '1410', '2960', '5050']})

print(df1)

    cus_id ref_num
0  WAT_281    1410
1  NIV_654    1410
2  HUL_602    2960
3  BRA_451    5050
```

As you can see, each customer is linked to a reference number. Moreover, different customers can be linked to the same number (e.g. customers `WAT_281` and `NIV_654` are linked to the reference number `1410`).

Next, I have a second DataFrame where each row describes a link between two customers.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'left_cus_id' : ['NOR_150', 'HUL_602', 'BAS_872', 'THI_028', 'PLA_467', 'ANT_360'], 
                    'right_cus_id' : ['NIV_654', 'THI_028', 'THI_028', 'PLA_467', 'GEN_089', 'KEF_100']})

print(df2)

  left_cus_id right_cus_id
0     NOR_150      NIV_654
1     HUL_602      THI_028
2     BAS_872      THI_028
3     THI_028      PLA_467
4     PLA_467      GEN_089
5     ANT_360      KEF_100
```

Visually, these two DataFrames create a network. To better explain this, I have created a diagram on a specific subset.

[image]

My goal is highlighted in red. Specifically, I want to "restructure" my original network to create a new DataFrame of links between customers and reference numbers. My final DataFrame should only include customers that are link to a reference number. For my example, it should look like so:

```
    cus_id ref_num
0  WAT_281    1410
1  NIV_654    1410
2  NOR_150    1410
3  HUL_602    2960
4  THI_028    2960
5  BAS_872    2960
6  PLA_467    2960
7  BRA_451    5050
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to achieve my goal. I also don't know how to create this network from the two initial DataFrames. I should note that my problem also includes more complex relationships like the following.

[image]

Any help on how to achieve my goal would be greatly appreciated. I am interested in the code that can solve this problem and a description of the steps involved in the process.

Comment: I put answer but now I saw that you have more complex relation as well. I think teh best will be to applyo some solutions which are used in network analysis/graph theory. I found this article https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/introduction-to-graph-theory-network-analysis-python-codes/ can think tomorrow how to implement it. There is part import networkx as nx and then we have to create all possible relations between nodes.

Comment: @HubertDudek Indeed, the relationships in my case are more complex and will require network analysis/graph theory. Thank you for the link, it is useful to understand the basics of graph theory.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple solution which I developed. Just mapped column from df2 with ids from df1.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cus_id' : ['WAT_281', 'NIV_654', 'HUL_602', 'BRA_451'],
                    'ref_num' : ['1410', '1410', '2960', '5050']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'left_cus_id' : ['NOR_150', 'HUL_602', 'BAS_872', 'THI_028', 'PLA_467', 'ANT_360'],
                    'right_cus_id' : ['NIV_654', 'THI_028', 'THI_028', 'PLA_467', 'GEN_089', 'KEF_100']})

df2['right_ref_num'] = df2['left_cus_id'].map(df1.set_index('cus_id')['ref_num'])

df2['left_ref_num'] = df2['right_cus_id'].map(df1.set_index('cus_id')['ref_num'])

df1 = df1.append(
    df2[['left_cus_id', 'left_ref_num']]
    .rename(columns={'left_cus_id': 'cus_id',
                     'left_ref_num': 'ref_num'})
    .dropna())
df1 = df1.append(
    df2[['right_cus_id', 'right_ref_num']]
    .rename(columns={'right_cus_id': 'cus_id',
                     'right_ref_num': 'ref_num'})
    .dropna())


print(df1.sort_values(by='ref_num').reset_index(drop=True))
```

Result:

```
    cus_id ref_num
0  WAT_281    1410
1  NIV_654    1410
2  NOR_150    1410
3  HUL_602    2960
4  THI_028    2960
5  BRA_451    5050
```